# How to get a value from the Row object in Spark Dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

for

```
averageCount = (wordCountsDF
                .groupBy().mean()).head()
```

I get

> Row(avg(count)=1.6666666666666667)

but when I try:

```
averageCount = (wordCountsDF
                .groupBy().mean()).head().getFloat(0)
```

I get the following error:

> AttributeError: getFloat
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 # TODO: Replace  with appropriate code
>   ----> 2 averageCount = (wordCountsDF
>         3                 .groupBy().mean()).head().getFloat(0)
>         4 
>         5 print averageCount
>
> /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py in **getattr**(self,
>   item)    1270             raise AttributeError(item)    1271
>   except ValueError:
>   -> 1272             raise AttributeError(item)    1273     1274     def **setattr**(self, key, value):
>
> AttributeError: getFloat

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 24):

I figured it out. This will return me the value:

```
averageCount = (wordCountsDF
                .groupBy().mean()).head()[0]
```

Answer (score 17):

This also works:

```
averageCount = (wordCountsDF
                .groupBy().mean('count').collect())[0][0]
print averageCount
```

Answer (score 5):

Dataframe rows are inherited from namedtuples (from the collections library), so while you can index them like a traditional tuple the way you did above, you probably want to access it by the name of its fields.  That is, after all, the point of named tuples, and it is also more robust to future changes.  Like this:

```
averageCount = wordCountsDF.groupBy().mean().head()['avg(jobs)']
```