# Iterate over a data frame

Tags: python, apache-spark

I am a beginner to spark.  I am trying to iterate on a data frame as follows( pyspark code )

```
df = sqlcontext.read.csv(path)
Arr = df.collect()
```

The array `arr` is an array of Rows. I need to know how can I get the column values from this array `arr`. I tried with the code below but getting some error

```
For row in arr :  print row.getString(1)
```

I get the following error [image]

Can some one help me how can I fetch the column values without using pandas

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49780094/pyspark-how-to-convert-spark-list-to-a-simple-list#comment86575954_49780094

Comment: Duplicate of [How to get a value from the Row object in Spark Dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37999657/6910411)

Answer (score 0):

you don't want to "`collect`" as this just brings the data to the master.
You can do `df.printSchema()` to see what columns you have (since you are reading a CSV you most likely want to read in the headers as in `spark.read.option('header', 'true').csv(path)`) and `df.show()` to see 20 sample lines (you can also specify how many rows)

Comment: Yup I know that’s it’s not a good idea to collect but the data I have for this use case fir this particular dataframe is very small , it’s a static data df hence collecting