# PySpark: DataFrame to RDD[DenseVector] and not RDD[Row]

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, rdd

I have a PySpark dataframe of the form:

```
+--------------------+
|            col_name|
+--------------------+
|[val1, val2, val3]  |
|[val1, val2, val3]  |
+--------------------+
```

I want to convert it to an RDD which is of a matrix form, so that I can ultimately convert it to a `RowMatrix`. However, when I use `df.rdd`, it gives me an RDD which has `Row` objects such as:

```
[Row(col_name=DenseVector([val1, val2, val3])),
Row(col_name=DenseVector([val1, val2, val3]))]
```

How do I work around this, so that I have an RDD with just my `DenseVector` objects and not `Row` objects which have the `DenseVector`s., i.e. of the form:

```
[DenseVector([val1, val2, val3]),
DenseVector([val1, val2, val3])]
```

How to achieve that?

Comment: The more important question is why you want to achieve that?

Comment: I want to compute the Cosine Similarities using .columnSimilarities(), for which I need to pass a RowMatrix of dense vectors.

Comment: Also this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37999657/how-to-get-a-value-from-the-row-object-in-spark-dataframe

Comment: @MichailN
[This](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/mllib/CosineSimilarity.scala) is the format I'm trying to convert my dataframe into.

Answer (score -3):

you can use:

```
df.rdd.map(row => <convert row to DenseVector>)
```

in scala you can get values of columns in a row with code:

```
row.getAs[Int](0)
```

Where Int 0 is index of the column. 
In scala DenseVector constructor expects array of doubles, so if you have 3 solumns you could do something like

```
df.rdd.map(row => row.getAs[DenseVector](0))
```

Comment: I did think about that, but how do I implement that pseudocode?

Comment: @TanmayBansal i've updated my answer. Didn't run it, though